# System crash when try to minimize gtk3 applications

Tags: unity, 15.04, themes

I have just upgraded my system from `Ubuntu[unity] 14.04 to Ubuntu[unity] 15.04 (64bit)`. Everything is working fine except a system crash. I have installed `ARC` theme and when I try to minimize a `gtk3` application (i.e gedit, nautilus) it crash and go to login screen without any warning. With `Ambiance`(only) theme minimize is working(not from keyboard). All `gtk2` applications (i.e google chrome, firefox) are working fine with all themes. I also tried keyboard combination `(Super + down)` to minimize all windows, and it crashes too. It shows some `FIFO underrun` error. I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**
Happens because gtk3's client side decorations do not play well with ubuntu.

**Workaround:**
Add this to your ~/.profile

```
export GTK_CSD=0
```